# How to ensure devenv.exe is not running when my msi is installed

Tags: wix, windows-installer, vsx

I am writing a VSPackage for Visual Studio 2008, and am deploying it with a WiX generated Msi.  As the end of the install, I am running "devenv.exe /setup" as required to get VS to notice my package.  However, this command will not succeed if there are any copies of Visual Studio running.

Currently, I tell people they have to close all copies of Visual Studio before installing, but I would prefer it be foolproof.  How can I check when someone runs my .msi if any copies of Visual Studio (devenv.exe) are running, and block them from installing my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WiX toolset has a CloseApps CustomAction that will close windows for you. It unfortuantely does not prompt with a list to close all the applications but the code would be a reasonable place to start.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(devenvIsRunning()) {} //in main routine of Installer class

static bool devenvIsRunning() //uses this subroutine
        {
            Process[] procList = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in procList)
            {
                if (p.ProcessName == "devenv")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An instance of Visual Studio is still running.\nPlease close all open instances of Visual Studio before continuing.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: +1, but it might be nice to let the user cancel the install instead of suspending it until all the devenvs are shut down.

Answer (score 2):

your best bet is to follow Rob's advide and put together a custom action to check if the process is running. I'd probably do something like see if it's running, try to close, if it's still running then schedule a reboot and do the devenv setup
via the RunOnce registry key.

If that's too much work then a bit of an ugly hack would be to use the windows command `TASKKILL` to exit the application. Not foolproof but it's better than nothing.

```
TASKKILL /IM devenv.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an installer class in your project and let it enumerate Running Processes

Comment: Installer classses are nasty.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use TASKKILL /IM devenv.exe  -F to kill the process and cmd had to be run as administrator